# How to get the list all files that are x.y but are not z/x.y?

Tags: grep, find, filter

I have a lot of `Settings.json` files on this machine.

I get the list of all of them using:

```
find / -name "Settings.json" 2>&-
```

But some of them are in directories that end to `Api`. For example:

```
/ClubApi/Settings.json
/CrmApi/Settings.json
```

I want to delete them all unless they belong to a directory that ends with `Api`. I can't do that.

I tried:

```
find / -name "Settings.json" 2>&- | xargs grep -v Api
```

But it doesn't work for filtering out the `Api` path.

How can I do that?

Comment: find . -name "Settings.json" | grep -v Api | xargs rm
This can delete but im not sure about your problem about filtering out the Api path.

Comment: @Dean, what if there's a file called `/tmp/.evil /etc/shadow /Settings.json`?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, don't get into the habit of *closing* the standard error stream with `2>&-` if you want to ignore errors.  It's safer to redirect it to `/dev/null` with `2>/dev/null`.  Some commands would terminate as soon as they tried and failed to write to the closed stream.

See e.g.

```bsh
{ echo 'error' >&2 && echo 'output'; } 2>&-
```

(which outputs nothing) vs.

```bsh
{ echo 'error' >&2 && echo 'output'; } 2>/dev/null
```

(which outputs `output`).

---

Use a `-path` test to avoid the files you don't want to affect:

```bsh
LC_ALL=C find / -type f ! -path '*Api/Settings.json' -name 'Settings.json' -print
```

Or, avoid those `*Api` directories completely if you don't even want to go near them:

```bsh
LC_ALL=C find / -name '*Api' -prune -o -type f -name 'Settings.json' -print
```

The `-prune` predicate "prunes" (cuts off, removes) a branch from the search tree, so the above `find` command would never even enter any directory whose name matches `*Api`.

Change `-print` in the above commands to `-exec rm {} +` to actually delete files.

Comment: Note that GNU `find` wouldn't *prune* a directory called `$'St\xe9phaneApi'` if run in a locale using the UTF-8 charset for instance. To prune all directories whose name ends in `Api` regardless of the charset it is encoded in, you could run `find` in the `C` locale (`LC_ALL=C find...`)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I can't reproduce the issue in your first comment, but that may be because locales on my (OpenBSD) system may be somewhat limited or buggy.

Comment: yes, that's down to the `fnmatch()` implementation that is being used `*` matches 0 or more characters. `$'\xe9'` cannot be decoded to a character in UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are going to do deletion it is best practice to first test the file list.

#### Improve `find` results with negative `-not -path` option.

```
find / -type f (-not -path "*[Aa]pi*") -and -name "Settings.json"  2>/dev/null
```

#### Filter `find` output with `grep`

```
find / -type f -name "Settings.json"  2>/dev/null | grep -v "[Aa]pi"
```

Once you have the correct list:

#### The easiest trick is to add `-delete` action to the `find` command:

This is **extremely dangerous** to run on `/`

```
find / -type f (-not -path "*[Aa]pi*") -and -name "Settings.json" -delete 2>/dev/null
```

#### More cautious deletion command is `rm` with `$(calculated list)`:

```
rm $(find / -type f (-not -path "*[Aa]pi*") -and -name "Settings.json"  2>/dev/null)
```

Comment: By running your first command, I get this error: `bash: syntax error near unexpected token \`('`

Comment: try to remove the `()`

Answer (score 0):

> I get the list of all of them using: … `find …`

You could also just use your shell to do that, instead of relying on find:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# To enable ** globbing
shopt -s globstar 

filename=Settings.json
for file in **/${filename} ; do
  if ! [[ "${file}" =~ Api/${filename}$ ]]; then
    # Do something, e.g. 
    # echo "${file}"
    # But beware! Files' and directories' names can contain newlines,
    # so I'd recommend either directly working on the file as you have it:
    # jq -r '.[0].command' < "${file}"
    # or printing it with the zero byte as terminator, instead of newline:
    # printf "%s\0", "${file}"
  fi
done
```